# Buscar el valor mas cercano en Crystal Reports

Tags: funciones, crystal-reports

Buen día, espero se encuentren bien.

Estoy trabajando con Crystal Reports y necesito agregar un campo que me informe donde esta el valor mas cercano a 80.
En el ejemplo de la imagen el resultado tendría que ser 80.77 ya que es el más próximo a este valor, existe algún función o de que manera puedo saber que valor es el más cercano, de antemano gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta seguro que la pregunta es sobre crystal reports? porque se supone que solo muestra datos...

Comment: Si, estoy trabajando en Crystal Reports.